# Detectar cuando se cierra una pagina o popup usando jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo una duda estoy abriendo una pagina `(popup)` usando `javascript` de esta manera :

```
    <a href="javascript:finestraSecundaria('ladin.php')">Haz clic Aqui</a>
    <script language=javascript>
    function finestraSecundaria (url){
    window.open(url, '_blank')
    }
    </script>
```

lo que pretendo es detectar el momento en que cierran la pagina `popup` o sea que en la pagina 01 detecte que la pagina 02 a sido cerrada.

espero alguna explicación gracias de ante mano .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asigna la ventana a una variable, donde puedes "escuchar" eventos, en este caso, onunload, aunque no hay la certeza de que se cerró la ventana, porque también se dispara cuando el usuario cambia de página:

```
<a href="javascript:finestraSecundaria('ladin.php')">Haz clic Aqui</a>
<script language=javascript>
function finestraSecundaria (url){
    var ventana = window.open(url, '_blank');
    // Hay que esperar a que se cargue la página
    ventana.onload = function() {
        // Ya se cargó la página y se puede asignar el evento final
        ventana.onunload = function() {
            console.log('Se cerró la ventana o el usuario cambió de página');
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: es posible que funcione en todos los navegadores y es posible enviar datos por ajax en ves de sacar informacion por la consola

Comment: Seguramente funcionará en navegadores recientes, pero puedes buscar información de compatibilidad en google. Por supuesto que puedes realizar otras acciones, tu pregunta era cómo detectar si se cerró la ventana y por eso solo puse como ejemplo el mensaje en consola.

Comment: si a si es es lo probare en algunos navegadores

Answer (score 5):

Puedes poner este script en tu html y te sirve para lo que buscas creo, de todas formas te lo dejo por aquí para que lo pruebes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            var e = e || window.event;
            if (e) {
                e.returnValue = alert('Estás por cerrar la página, cuidado!');
            }
        }
    </script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Detectar</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>DETECTAR EL CIERRE DE LA PÁGINA WEB - INTENTA CERRAR LA PÁGINA</h1>            
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente lo que hace es que si vas a cerrar la pagina te salte un mensaje en el navegador. Espero que te sirva para lo que quieres.

Comment: no es para que salga un mensaje al cerrar la pagina . lo que busco es que salga una alerta en la pagina padre o sea en pagina 01 al cerrar la pagina 02 igual se agradece tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

asigna una variable a window.open(url, '_blank') por ejemplo
var prueba = window.open(url, '_blank'), luego dentro de un setInterval de 1 segundo de tiempo coloca un if(prueba.closed) cuando se cierre el popup o ventana emergente este sera verdadero y puedes desarrollar tu logica.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).